# How long does it take to silver a weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, crafting

PHB 148 on silvered weapons:

> You can silver a single weapon or ten pieces of ammunition for 100gp. This cost represents not only the price of the silver, but the time and expertise needed to add silver to the weapon without making it less effective.

The rules are not specific as to how much silver is required, or rather, how much of that 100gp is in silver components. With no particular reference, I can only assume it's half the cost (50gp worth of silver). This seems to be supported by the following:

PHB 187 on crafting:

> For every day of downtime you spend crafting, you can craft one or more items with a total market value not exceeding 5gp, and you must expend raw materials worth half the total market value.

If raw materials is half of the 100gp value of silvering, does this mean that it would take 20 days to augment a weapon with 50gp worth of silver? Furthermore, would it also take 20 days if the PCs offered 100gp for a professional craftsman to do the same?

Answer (score 15):

The 100 gp represents both the materials cost and the labour cost. A smith will therefore take 20 days to do this. If the character is only paying for the material then it will cost them 50 gp, but will still take 20 days.

Comment: If the work costs 50 gp, why do you say it takes 20 days and not 10?

Comment: The time taken depends on the total cost of the item, not the discounted cost.

Comment: If it has to be the total cost of the item, why don't you count the price of the weapon itself?

Comment: Because we are silvering an existing weapon/ammunition. If we were crafting the weapon as well then, yes, that would increase time and money (but again, the time would be based on materials and labour cost of the item, not just the materials cost).

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker, are you sure it is 20 days? I ask as according to the PHB 187 as mentioned in the question it specifically states 'You' so surely a trained smith would take less time?